# Flask website -- 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, digital-ocean

I cannot for the life of me figure of why this flask application I'm trying to launch is not working. I am running it on a $5 Digital Ocean droplet. Here's (hopefully) everything you need to know about it:

Directory layout (contained within `/var/www/`):

```
FlaskApp
    FlaskApp
        __init__.py
        static
        templates
        venv
    flaskapp.wsgi
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "yay it worked"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`flaskapp.wsgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

`FlaskApp.conf` (contained in `/etc/apache2/sites-availble`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName the.ip.blah.blah
        ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`venv` was created from calling `virtualenv venv` within `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/`. I installed flask in `venv` using `pip install flask` after entering `venv` using `source venv/bin/activate`.

Wsgi has been enabled (`a2enmod wsgi`). FlaskApp.conf was enabled (`a2ensite FlaskApp`). And, finally, I restarted apache many times, but to no success (`service apache2 restart`).

I was following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) guide on how to set up a flask application.

Here is a screenshot of what my error looks like:

[image: The Error]

Any help on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I found the problem: `ImportError: No module named flask`. This is a little strange since I did do `pip install flask` within the virtualenv. When I just open a python console session in the virtualenv and try `import flask` I get no error, so not sure what's going on.

Also, how is this application even using `venv`? I don't see it getting accessed anywhere so how is it even using it? Perhaps this is why i'm getting the `ImportError`, because I only have flask installed on the virtualenv but it's not being used?

Comment: Did you look in the apache server error log, as the error page suggests?

Comment: @JohnGordon Where do I check the apache server error log?

Comment: I found the problem. Look at the edit I made to the post.

Comment: I have mine set up without a virtualenv. I just installed Flask globally. Not sure if it's best practices, but it works.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Yes, considering the same myself. I don't plan on using this web server for anything but this flask app anyway so I don't see why not. And, after a bit of research, I'm not the only one who's been having problems with this tutorial. It seems whoever made it made you make a virtualenv, but then forgets to use it.

Comment: You can likely just change the shebang at the top of your wsgi file to point to the python binary for your venv.  Something like `#!/some/path/to/bin/python`

Comment: To find the path to the `correct` python, activate the virtualenv and run `which python`

Comment: @RobertR Go for it. Deactivate the virtual environment, then do a pip install globally.

Comment: I disagree about installing globally.  I would opt for the venv first, but hey... it's your server - do with it as you please.

Comment: @sberry I'd definitely rather use a virtualenv, but it seems to be causing problems. Anyway, I tried changing the shebang to the result of `which python` and then restarted apache but it didn't work. Same old `ImportError` in the logs too.

Comment: You can also try what is listed under "Create the wsgi file" here: http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/.  Mainly it is the `import site` and `site.addsitedir(...)` you would want.  One of the reasons I really like uwsgi + nginx.

Comment: @sberry Woohoo it worked! Thanks a lot. If you want to put your answer in a proper answer in stead of a comment I'll accept it.

Comment: You should just delete the shebang line in the WSGI script file as it isn't used for anything. The Python version/installation is dictated by what mod_wsgi was compiled against, not what is defined by the file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is essentially that you are installing Flask, and possibly other required libraries, in a virtual environment but the python (wsgi interface) is running with the system python which does not have these extra libraries installed.

I have very little recent experience running Python on Apache (I come from an era of mod_python and cgi), but apparently one way to handle this is to use the `site` package to add the `site-packages` from your venv to the Python that is executed.  This would go in your `.wsgi` file.

```
import site

site.addsitedir('/path/to/your/venv/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages')
```

Comment: Try not to use ``site.addsitedir()``. Use mod_wsgi daemon mode (which is the recommended method) and when you define ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` use the ``python-home`` option to specify the location of the virtual environment. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve  your problem is to add tell your wsgi file about your virtual environment and activate it:
put the following code in your  your flaskapp.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

and restart apache.
hope it will help!
find more [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/)