# How to deploy flask app on AWS EC2 - Internal Server Error?

Tags: python, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I would like to deploy flask app on AWS EC2. But I have encountered **500 Internal Server Error**.

First, I have installed apache webserver and mod_wsgi.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py2
```

I've installed pip3 and flask.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install flask
```

This is the flask.wsgi file in the flaskapp directory.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')

from flaskapp  import app as application
```

I've make the mod_wsgi enable.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Finally, I have restarted apache2.

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

When I go to AWS EC2 domain, I got an **500 Internal Server Error**.

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My flaskapp should run on python3.

I don't know how to handle this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at your django application logs or the Apache logs, which are probably in `/var/log/apache` or `/var/log/httpd`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There isn't anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. And there is no httpd directory in `/var/log` directory.

Comment: That could indicate the problems are coming from the `wsgi` module and it's suppressing the log output because Apache defaults to `warn` level logging. Try setting `LogLevel info` in your `httpd.conf` to surface more messages in your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar type of question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656702/flask-website-500-internal-server-error).

Quoting from the answer:

> The problem is essentially that you are installing Flask, and possibly other required libraries, in a virtual environment but the python (wsgi interface) is running with the system python which does not have these extra libraries installed.
>
> apparently one way to handle this is to use the `site` package to add the `site-packages` from your venv to the Python that is executed. This would go in your `.wsgi` file.

```
import site

site.addsitedir('/path/to/your/venv/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages')
```

Comment: Adding the ``site-packages`` directory directly is not recommended. See the mod_wsgi documentation on how to use virtual environments. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html