# ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'FlaskApp' (unknown location)

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) from digital ocean.

I got all the way to the last step when I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

My app is structured like the following:

```
|--------FlaskApp
|----------------FlaskApp
|-----------------------static
|-----------------------templates
|-----------------------venv
|-----------------------__init__.py
|----------------flaskapp.wsgi
```

My `__init__.py` contains the following:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My flaskapp.wsgi contains the following:

```
import sys
import logging
import site

site.addsitedir('/var/www/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages')

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'key'
```

I had added the bit about importing site after reading this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656702/flask-website-500-internal-server-error)

When I look into /var/www/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages I can in fact see that packages I need and when I run python3, and import flask, it does load.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: by any chance, do you have more that 1 version of python installed?

Comment: in that venv? I do not

Comment: for what it is worth, I was able to install flask into the site-packages folder and import flask in python3 and have updated the question

Comment: what is the output for `pip install flask` ?